# PyDrive での認証を行うプログラムが、PyInstaller で exe 化すると正常に動かない

Tags: python, python3, google-api, pyinstaller

PyDrive を用いてGoogleドライブからデスクトップにファイルをダウンロードするプログラムを作成し、正常に動作することを確認しました。

しかし、このファイルをexe化したところ、想定通りの動作をせず一瞬ウィンドウが立ち上がった後すぐ閉じてしまいました。原因や確認すべき項目がありましたらご教示頂けますか。

なお、Pythonのバージョンは3.6で、inputやprintだけの簡単な内容のものであれば問題なくexe化できました。
そもそもPyDrive認証を含むpyファイルのexe化はできないものなのでしょうか？

#### pyファイルの中身

```
# 必要なライブラリのインポート
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive  
file_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# OAuth認証を行う
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.CommandLineAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# ファイルをGoogleドライブからダウンロード
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
f.GetContentFile('abc.bat')
```

exe化のコマンドは `py -m PyInstaller dl.py --onefile` で、結果は以下の通りです。
※pyファイルの名前は「dl.py」
※exe化はコマンドプロンプトにて実施

```
 　　42 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
    142 INFO: Python: 3.6.8
    142 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
    144 INFO: wrote C:\Users\admin\Desktop\dl.spec
    145 INFO: UPX is not available.
    150 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
    ['C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop', 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop']
    151 INFO: checking Analysis
    152 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
    152 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
    159 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
    175 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
    3614 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
    3690 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
    3693 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
      required by C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
    3778 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\admin\Desktop\dl.py
    3976 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
    4494 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
    4496 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib'
    5973 INFO: Processing module hooks...
    5973 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
    5976 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
    5977 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
    6149 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-google.api_core.py"...
    6152 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-httplib2.py"...
    6154 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
    6724 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
    6810 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
    6812 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
    6812 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
    6813 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
    7190 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
    7571 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
    7573 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
    8063 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
    8296 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
    8308 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
    8312 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
    8316 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
    8318 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
    8319 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
    8327 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
    8748 INFO: Looking for eggs
    8748 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python36.dll
    8749 INFO: Found binding redirects:
    []
    8759 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\admin\Desktop\build\dl\warn-dl.txt
    8929 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\admin\Desktop\build\dl\xref-dl.html
    8967 INFO: checking PYZ
    8967 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
    8968 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\build\dl\PYZ-00.pyz
    10427 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\build\dl\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
    10468 INFO: checking PKG
    10468 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
    10469 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
    13745 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
    13749 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
    13750 INFO: checking EXE
    13750 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
    13750 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
    13751 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\admin\Desktop\dist\dl.exe
    13768 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

コマンドプロンプトにてexeファイルを実行した結果は以下の通りです。

```
    C:\Users\admin\Desktop>dl.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\dl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 7, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\apiclient\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import discovery
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 67, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.http import build_http
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 67, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.model import JsonModel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\model.py", line 36, in <module>
    _LIBRARY_VERSION = pkg_resources.get_distribution("google-api-python-client").version
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 479, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 355, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 898, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 784, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[21036] Failed to execute script dl
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>
```

exe実行時のエラーメッセージ`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application`
を確認しましたが、既にgoogle-api-python-clientはインストール/アップグレード済です。
他のサイトでも探してみましたが、これといった解決方法が見つかりませんでした。

Comment: >kumitatepazuru様
コマンドプロンプトにて作成したexeファイルを実行した結果を記載しました。

Comment: そのまま該当するわけでは無いでしょうし、応用できるか不明ですが、この記事の情報が参考になるかも。[Pyinstallerを使ってPythonコードから生成した実行ファイルについて、実行時エラーModuleNotFoundErrorを回避](https://qiita.com/kanedaq/items/e65507878c52ad67d002)

Answer (score 0):

コマンドプロンプトから実行してみてください。多分、その部分でエラーが出ていると思います。